# Animating a Circle stretching into a rounded rectangle

Tags: android, user-interface, android-animation, android-canvas, android-custom-view

I'm trying to animate bunch of circles slowly turning into vertically stretched- rounded rectangles, [image: something like this]

I'm referencing  [AVLoadingIndicatorView](https://github.com/81813780/AVLoadingIndicatorView) (5th row 3rd column in the demo .gif) i was able to draw the circles, but it's giving me hard time animating it.
here is my code to draw circles:

```
void draw(){...
 float startX=(getWidth()/2)-(total/2) ;
    for (int i=1;i<18;i++){
        float position=startX+(30*i);// position the circle into middle(w.r.t existing ones)
        canvas.scale(1.5f,1.5f);
        canvas.drawCircle(position,getHeight()/2,8,paint);
    }
```

here is the createAnimation method from AVLoadingIndicator:

```
 @Override
public List<Animator> createAnimation() {
    List<Animator> animators=new ArrayList<>();
    long[] delays=new long[]{100,200,300,400,500};
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        final int index=i;
        ValueAnimator scaleAnim=ValueAnimator.ofFloat(1, 0.4f, 1);
        scaleAnim.setDuration(1000);
        scaleAnim.setRepeatCount(-1);
        scaleAnim.setStartDelay(delays[i]);
        scaleAnim.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation) {
                scaleYFloats[index] = (float) animation.getAnimatedValue();
                postInvalidate();
            }
        });
        scaleAnim.start();
        animators.add(scaleAnim);
    }
    return animators;
}
```

output gives a view with bunch of circles just sitting there doing nothing...
what am i doing wrong? and how can i achieve the described animation..??